# Finding Start date and End date for same value using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet looks like below. I want the start date and end date for a task. Ex: for the `ABC` task the start date is "`2015-04-01`" and the end date is "`2015-04-04`". How to summarize the dates?

```
Row# | Date       |Task
-----+------------+-----
1    | 2015-04-01 | ABC  
2    | 2015-04-02 | ABC
3    | 2015-04-05 | 123
4    | 2015-04-01 | 123
5    | 2015-04-04 | ABC
6    | 2015-04-01 | 123
7    | 2015-04-05 | 123
8    | 2015-04-01 | ABC
```

Comment: This site is not a free coding service. We can help when you get stuck, though, so show your code so far and explain where you need help. Edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are too lazy to come up with a VBA code on your own try having a pivot do it. Have a data table.

```
Row# | Date       |Task | Date2
-----+------------+-----+----------------
1    | 2015-04-01 | ABC | =A2 [2015-04-01]
2    | 2015-04-02 | ABC | 
3    | 2015-04-05 | 123 | 
4    | 2015-04-01 | 123 | 
5    | 2015-04-04 | ABC | 
6    | 2015-04-01 | 123 | 
7    | 2015-04-05 | 123 | 
8    | 2015-04-01 | ABC |
```

The output pivot will look like this:

```
Row# | Task | Min / Date | Max / Date2
-----+------+------------+-------------
1    | 123  | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-05
2    | ABC  | 2015-04-01 | 2015-04-04
```

Answer (score 0):

The next could be improved, but it works:

```
Sub Fechas()
        Dim startDate As Date
        Dim endDate As Date        
        Dim selected As String
        startDate = #1/1/2999#
        endDate = #1/1/1900#
        'Item you want to know the start/end dates
        'So select it before run the macro (i.e. ABC from Task)
        selected = ActiveCell.Value
        'Change the Range as you will
        Range("B1").Select
        Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
        If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = selected) Then
            If ActiveCell.Value < startDate Then startDate = ActiveCell.Value
            If ActiveCell.Value > endDate Then endDate = ActiveCell.Value
        Else
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
        If startDate = endDate Then
        MsgBox "For: " & selected & Chr$(13) & "Start date: " & startDate & Chr$(13) & "Unknown End date/Same Dates"
        Else
        MsgBox "For: " & selected & Chr$(13) & "Start date: " & startDate & Chr$(13) & "End Date: " & endDate
        End If
    End Sub
```